# RoR and Rspec setting up a test using a while loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

Ok so I want to create a test for checking that all pages have a certain title. However I thought it would be nice if I could include the page titles in an `array` so that I wouldn't have to duplicate the block for each page. And it would allow me to test additional pages by just modifying the `pages array`.

The issue I am having is that the page variable is not being interpolated in the test. So is this a syntax error or does Rspec not allow interpolation within the `it should do...` block?

```
describe "LayoutLinks" do

    page = ["home", "contact", "about", "help"]
    i = page.count
    x = 0

    while x < i  
        it "should have a #{page[x]} page" do
        get "#{page[x]}"
        response.should have_selector("title", :content => "#{page[x]}")
        end
    x += 1
    end

end
```

Test shows the following failures:

```
  1) PagesController LayoutLinks should have a help page
     Failure/Error: get "#{page[x]}"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"pages", :action=>""}
     # ./spec/controllers/layout_links_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) PagesController LayoutLinks should have a contact page
     Failure/Error: get "#{page[x]}"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"pages", :action=>""}
     # ./spec/controllers/layout_links_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) PagesController LayoutLinks should have a about page
     Failure/Error: get "#{page[x]}"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"pages", :action=>""}
     # ./spec/controllers/layout_links_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) PagesController LayoutLinks should have a home page
     Failure/Error: get "#{page[x]}"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"pages", :action=>""}
```

Failure error here is obvious. It shouldn't say get `"#{page[x]}"` but rather it should be `get home` and `get about`, etc...

How do I remedy? Thanks for the help. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
describe "LayoutLinks" do
  %w(home contact about help).each do |page|
    it "should have a #{page} page" do
      get page
      response.should have_selector("title", content: page)
    end
  end
end
```

%w creates an array of strings (spaces become commas, so you get ["home", "contact", etc])

Comment: The suggestion is refactored and the get is routing correctly, however `page` is not being interpolated as the content. Nice try. Btw I tired unsuccessfully: `:content => "#{page}"` too.

Comment: The following edit `response.should have_selector('title', :content => @page)` makes me green. Thanks!